Why is it that when passing the first string element into a bool array, the element is always equal to the length of the array?
I initialize a variable g consisting of only digits not exceeding 2, then I initialize a bool array consisting of three elements and at f[g[0]] I get an exception, “The index was outside the bounds of the array.” since f[3] why g[0] = f.length always regardless of the length of g and the value of g[0] ?
string g = "022";

bool[] f = { true, true, true };

Console.WriteLine(f[(int)g[0]]);
Console.ReadLine();


Just write (int)"0" to console and you will see.

How do you come to the conclusion that g[0] is always equal f.length? Why is g[0] being larger then f.length not a consideration?

Your conclussion that "g[0] = f.length always regardless of the length of g and the value of g[0]" is actually incorrect, as explained below:
Since g is a string, g[0] is a char.
(int)g[0] is converting the ASCII value of the character to int.
The ASCII value of '0' is 48.
Therefore f[(int)g[0]] is attempting to access f at index 48 which is invalid.
If you want to access f at index 0 (the first character in g), you can use:
f[(int)(g[0] -'0']

By subtracting '0' (the ASCII of '0') you will get the numeric value of the character.
Complete example:
string g = "022";
bool[] f = { true, false, true };
Console.WriteLine(f[(int)(g[0] -'0')]); 

Output:
True

